# AMPPS - Local Dev Server URL without 127.0.0.1 or localhost, How to configure?

Tags: localhost, ampps

I'm just setting up a new computer and have installed AMPPS.

The problem I am having is that the URL is using http://localhost/test.silva/ but I need it to be http://test.silva

I have tried the following:-

```
Edit Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/httpd.conf 

change <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>  (line 510 on my machine) 

to  <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Then restarted Apache but this doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

FYI: I'm on a Macbook